# A dataset has a partition key built from its primary sorting key. At query time, Spark doesn't search a key in a specific partition and read them all

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

With *Apache Spark*, I created some accounting data about French cities.
The `Dataset` has this main fields :

```
city_code, establishment_id, account_number, amount, city name,  department  
29045    , 2904521051      , 6105          , 23.51 , Dirinon  ,  29
29046    , 2907425498      , 4031          , 17.20 , Douarnenez, 29
```

1. It is sorted by an `orderBy("city_code", "establishment_id", "account_number")`
2. then partitioned by a `repartition(col("department"))`
   They're a bit more than 100 department in France : `01` to `95`, and some special cases like `2A`, `2B`, and `971`, `972`, `973`, `974`, `976`. A department is string of three characters.
3. and saved under `Parquet` files.

I take a look in the parquet file folder and find 200 blocks inside.
I'm a bit surprised : shouldn't I have found around 100 instead ? One per department ?

Then, I attempt a query. I ask for accounting data of the city `29046`. It's the only parameter of the function that returns its related accounts, for all its establishments.
I'm receiving them well, but my logs inform me that all the blocks of my parquet file have been red to do so. I was expecting that only one would have been needed : the one containing the partition `29`.

I start wondering myself : But why am I believing this ? How could *Apache Spark* really know that any city code of the shape `29xxx` will have to be searched in the partition having for code `29` ?

I'm not understanding partitioning well, here. I'm confusing about keys on one side, partition keys on the other side : they are not so linked that I'm believing.
How many mistakes did I wrote here, and what should I do to achieve the result I'm looking for ?

---

I've attempted the change @mck suggested in an answer.

From the `comptes` dataset I have, I executed these actions with first a parquet file **without** `substr(city_code, 1, 2)` for partition :

```java
comptes = comptes.orderBy("codeCommune", "siret", "numeroCompte");
comptes = comptes.withColumn("partitionCommune", substring(col("codeCommune"), 1, 2));
comptes = comptes.repartition(col("partitionCommune"));
comptes.write().parquet("myStore");
```

Followed by a query of the `codeCommune` 29046.

```java
Dataset<Row> comptes = session.read().parquet("myStore");
comptes.where(col("codeCommune").equalTo("29046")).show();
```

- the dataset generation and writing on disk (200 blocks) takes 697s.
- the query attempt on city code `29046` reads all the 200 blocks and takes 9s.

Then, I've exchanged the line writing the parquet file with this one, and reran the generation of the parquet file and the query. Now it is creating a parquet file **with** partition:

```java
comptes.write().partitionBy("partitionCommune").parquet("myStore");
```

- The generation of the dataset and its writing on disk (nearly 500 blocks) takes 875s.
- The query of the `city_code` 29046 reads all the 500 blocks and takes around 9s too.

(EDIT: I had a bug, the `orderBy` transform wasn't the last before writing parquet file and my data wasn't sorted causing a file of 20,000 blocks at the end, because attempting to write as partitioned what was unsorted data !)

So, it works.

Comment: did you specify `.write.partitionBy(col("department"))`?

Comment: @mck No, I used the `Dataset` method `repartition(Column... partitionExprs)`. Is its behavior different than `.write.partitionBy(col("department"))` ? Or must `.write.partitionBy(col("department"))` be called even if a `repartition(...)` has been done before ?

Comment: Yes, both have to be called. e.g. `df.repartition(...).write.partitionBy(...)`.

Comment: @mck but by what mechanism does Spark know that it will have to search for city code `29046` in the partition of the department `29` ? A sort of index is created at the top of parquet files ?

Comment: Is there a relationship between the city code and the department?

Comment: The index is really the partition column. The parquet folder names contain the value of the partitioning column.

Comment: Then, asking for `city_code = 29046` causes a sequential search in the block, and the `orderBy("city_code", "establishment_id", "account_number")` I did before writing is useless ? Should I have attempted a `repartitionBy("city_code", "establishment_id", "account_number")` instead ? Would this had sense ? But then my 100 partitions, one per department, would be gone. The city code and the department have a relationship : from the first two character of the city_code you have the department. But this rule isn't written anywhere in my code.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan I addressed your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition), if you do `df.repartition` based on a column, and does not specify the number of partitions, it will result in a default number of partitions, which is 200. That's why you got 200 blocks.

The partitioning behaviour of the writer (`.write.partitionBy`) is slightly different from that of the dataframe. The number of partitions (aka blocks/files) it will create is equal to the number of distinct values in the partitioning column you specified (`N`). If you don't specify one, the default behaviour is to dump each partition of the dataframe to a separate file. If you do specify one, the behaviour would be to dump each partition of the dataframe to `N` separate files (empty partitions are not dumped).

To achieve what you want, the way is to specify partitioning of both the dataframe and the writer. e.g.

```
df.repartition('col').write.partitionBy('col').parquet('path')
```

For your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66656280/im-confused-with-keys-used-for-sorting-a-dataset-and-partition-keys-i-expect-s/66656498?noredirect=1#comment117831977_66656280), I think you can partition by the first two digits of the city code and the department, e.g.

```
df.withColumn('city_code_first_two', F.substring('city_code', 1, 2)).repartition('department', 'city_code_first_two').write.partitionBy('department', 'city_code_first_two').parquet('path')
```

This should result in the same number of files, provided that there is a 1-to-1 relationship between `department` and `city_code_first_two`.

Comment: How can I ensure that `repartition` (or another function managing partitions) will create no more than the - let say - 103 departments needed, and one partition per department ? Because even before writing parquet file it's important : data are mostly gathered in the same department.

Comment: Doing `.repartition('department')` will result in 103 filled partitions and 97 empty partitions. Is that okay for your needs?

Comment: If you have a rough idea of how many departments there will be, you can specify a slightly larger value to reduce the number of empty partitions, e.g. sth like `df.repartition(150, 'department')`

Comment: I've tried only the first part of your solution, yet. If I do the `write.partitionBy('codeDepartement')` the parquet file has folders named `codeDepartement=01`, `codeDepartement=2A`, `codeDepartement=971` and each folder has 200 files in it. But it urges me to link the `city_code` with `department`, because now, if I try to query the `city_code = 29046` it takes days : Spark attempts to read 100 x 200 files !

Answer (score 2):

> "I expect Spark to search for a key in a specific partition but it's not the case"

Spark does not keep track of which keys are going to which partition. Which means if you filter on a particular value in a column used for partitioning it still has to go through all partitions.

Partitioning your Dataset by a column just guarantees that the same values in the column are going to the same partition which can give you a performance benefit when processing the data as each partition is processed on a single executor for narrow transformations.

Remember that Spark is a distributed computation engine not an indexable data storage.

As described in the other answer you can partition your data by one or more columns when storing the data. In addition, you can also bucket your data.

By the way, if you find 200 too much you can always specify the number of partitions in

```
df.repartition(#ofPartitions, Column... partitionExprs)
```